# Pagination not working properly in jquery

Tags: jquery

When I put search item, first pagination is shows the rows for searched item but after that the pagination does not populating the searched rows, instead it shows default rows. So what i want is when i click pagination 2, the table should show the searched item rows not the default rows. Basically, I am trying to develop datatable sort of thing, where i can incorporate pagination, search option,etc

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rowsShown = 5;
  var rowsTotal = $('#data tr').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  $("#error").hide();
  $("#total").html(rowsTotal);
  $("#nav").show();

  $('#data tr').hide();
  $('#data tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();

  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '" class="pagination">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
  }

  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active').css({
    'color': '#1D6185',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'background-color': '#86CCF1'
  });

  $('#nav a').click(function() {
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).addClass('active').css({
      'color': '#1D6185',
      'font-weight': 'bold',
      'background-color': '#86CCF1'
    });
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;

    $('#data tr').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).css('display', 'table-row').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);

  });
  //-------------search---------  

  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('#data tr').hide();
    $("#total").hide();
    $('#nav').empty();
    var value = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
    var resultCount = 0;

    $('#data tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
        resultCount++;
      }
    });

    $("#total").html(resultCount).show();
    var Search_rowsShown = 5;
    var Search_numPages = resultCount / Search_rowsShown;



    var search_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#data tr").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_value) > -1

      })
      .slice(0, 5)
      .show();

    for (j = 0; j < Search_numPages; j++) {
      var Search_pageNum = j + 1;
      $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + j + '">' + Search_pageNum + '</a> ');
    }

    $('#nav a:first').addClass('active').css({
      'color': 'red',
      'font-weight': 'bold'
    });

    $('#nav a').click(function() {
      $('#nav a').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
      $(this).addClass('active').css({
        'color': 'red',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
      });
      var search_currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
      var search_startItem = search_currPage * Search_rowsShown;
      var search_endItem = search_startItem + Search_rowsShown;

      $('#data tr').hide().slice(search_startItem, search_endItem).css('display', 'table-row').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    });


    if (resultCount == 0) {
      $("#error").html("No Data").show();
      $("#total").hide();
      $("#nav").hide();
      $("#totentry").hide();
    } else {
      $("#error").hide();
      $("#total").show();
      $("#nav").show();
      $("#totentry").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="tab" id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Report/Table Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"><span class="srch">Search :</span><input type="text" id="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Please enter the text here..." /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SL.No</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="footer">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span id="totentry">Total Entry :</span><span id="total"></span></td>
      <td align="center"><span id="error"></span></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="nav" class="nav"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the html as well?

Comment: You can run the snippet code above and put 1 in search box and click pagination 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take, the reason why you always the original data when using the pagination after a search is that, the `<tr>` that doesnt match the search are still there but only hidden.

So, I had to store the initial `<tr>` `nodes` into a variable before any searches and always use that as the base to search for. Then in the search function, you remove all the `<tr>`s and replace it with the returned from the search results by appending to the `#data / <tbody>`

**Here is a working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rowsShown = 5;
  var rowsTotal = $('#data tr').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  $("#error").hide();
  $("#total").html(rowsTotal);
  $("#nav").show();

  let initialTBody = $('#data tr')
  $('#data tr').hide();
  initialTBody.slice(0, rowsShown).show();


  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '" class="pagination">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
  }

  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active').css({
    'color': '#1D6185',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'background-color': '#86CCF1'
  });

  $('#nav a').click(function() {
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).addClass('active').css({
      'color': '#1D6185',
      'font-weight': 'bold',
      'background-color': '#86CCF1'
    });


    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;

    $('#data tr').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).css('display', 'table-row').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);

  });
  //-------------search---------  

  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $('#data tr').remove();
    $("#total").hide();
    $('#nav').empty();
    var value = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();
    var resultCount = 0;

    initialTBody.each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1) {
        resultCount++;
      }
    });

    $("#total").html(resultCount).show();
    var Search_rowsShown = 5;
    var Search_numPages = resultCount / Search_rowsShown;



    var search_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let resultsTBody = initialTBody.filter(function() {
      //return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_value) > -1

      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search_value) > -1) {
        return $(this)
      }

    })


    resultsTBody.slice(0, Search_rowsShown).show();

    $('#data').append(resultsTBody)

    for (j = 0; j < Search_numPages; j++) {
      var Search_pageNum = j + 1;
      $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + j + '">' + Search_pageNum + '</a> ');
    }

    $('#nav a:first').addClass('active').css({
      'color': 'red',
      'font-weight': 'bold'
    });


    $('#nav a').click(function() {
      $('#nav a').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
      $(this).addClass('active').css({
        'color': 'red',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
      });
      var search_currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
      var search_startItem = search_currPage * Search_rowsShown;
      var search_endItem = search_startItem + Search_rowsShown;

      $('#data tr').hide().slice(search_startItem, search_endItem).css('display', 'table-row').animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    });

    if (resultCount == 0) {
      $("#error").html("No Data").show();
      $("#total").hide();
      $("#nav").hide();
      $("#totentry").hide();
    } else {
      $("#error").hide();
      $("#total").show();
      $("#nav").show();
      $("#totentry").show();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="tab" id="tab">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Report/Table Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"><span class="srch">Search :</span><input type="text" id="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Please enter the text here..." /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SL.No</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
      <td>Row 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
      <td>Row 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
      <td>Row 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
      <td>Row 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
      <td>Row 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
      <td>Row 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
      <td>Row 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
      <td>Row 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
      <td>Row 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
      <td>Row 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
      <td>Row 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
      <td>Row 22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
      <td>Row 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
      <td>Row 24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="footer">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span id="totentry">Total Entry :</span><span id="total"></span></td>
      <td align="center"><span id="error"></span></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="nav" class="nav"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>


</html>
```

Comment: Great work! Thanks...but small issue still persist.
When i delete the searched number say " 5" or any other number....and delete or backspace that number in search field, table should display the initial default records but currently, its adding up the search item data....can you please help me out :)

Comment: I just put the "if statement" and that solved my problem :)
if($("#search").val()==''){
  $('#data tr').hide();
  initialTBody.slice(0, rowsShown).show();
  }

Comment: I was about to edit my code. but anyway, it's great to have helped.

Comment: One more issue...when i search for say "16" and then when i delete just 6 and keep 1 only on search bar....it should give the result for "1" only but it appends for "16"
Can you please help me out..thanks